# Firebase signInWithCustomToken not expired?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

i feel stupid for asking this, but im going to ask anyway

im still new in firebase and now trying to use signInWithCustomToken to be able to edit my users data as admin
this is my firebase database realtime rules

```
{
          "rules": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            "users": {
              "$user_id": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": "$user_id == auth.uid"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

this is my client side(?) code, i use ajax to send username and password to CI controller, then from there the controller will send the value to nodejs

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Umum/senddata/"+user+"/"+pass
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(msg).catch(function(error) {
                  // Handle Errors here.
                  var errorCode = error.code;
                  var errorMessage = error.message;
                  if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-custom-token') {
                    alert('The token you provided is not valid.');
} else {
                                console.error(error);
                                }
                            });
                        }) 

                    });
```

and this is my node js code. first i need to check if username exist in firebase, then i will get the UID to create customtoken, then send the customtoken back to clientside

```
app.post('/sendata', function(req, res) {
    var content = req.body;
    admin.database().ref('/admins').orderByChild('username').equalTo(content.username).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            admin.auth().createCustomToken(childSnapshot.val().adminuid).then(function(customToken) {
                console.log("customtoken : " + customToken);
                //to-do: forward the message to the connected nodes.
                res.end(customToken);
                admin.auth().verifyIdToken(customToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
                    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
                    console.log("uidnya : " + uid);
                    // ...
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    // Handle error
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

now the problem is, people said the token will expires in 1 hour.
what they mean by expires? after expires they cant edit the users data or what?
because mine still work, im still able to edit my users data even after 1 hours without relogin.
or maybe my signInWithCustomToken is wrong?
but i tried to console.log and it return correct user i use to login
what will happen if the token expires?

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the custom token with the ID token.

The custom token you return to the client expires after one hour. Normally that is fine as you only need to use it once with `signInWithCustomToken`. This will sign in the user on the client side. In exchange a Firebase ID token and refresh token will be returned by the Firebase Auth server and stored on the client (the Firebase ID token is used to check if a user is authenticated and access things like Firebase Realtime database/Firestore/etc). This is what you call `verifyIdToken` on. The Firebase ID token will expire after one hour but the Firebase refresh token will allow the client to refresh that ID token when it does.